# SVC HANDLER: ARM cortex m processor

Tags: arm

There was no enough information regarding the svc on the internet . i learned how SVC  handler is working but the thing is i am not getting why it is stacking the register R0,R1,R2,R3 and R12 onto the stack. unless it has a purpose it wont store so what is the information ,which is that important to the processor ,present  in these registers.

and any one pls suggest how to learn ARM Cortex M3?
How to start learning so that there wont be any confusions in the basic things like the one above.
thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is because each time you call a function, the ABI describes that:

- Registers `r0`-`r3` can contain the parameters, and can be used as scratch register. This means that there is no need for the function to save them (They will be modified)
- Other registers need to be saved by the function, ie they need to be restored to the previous value when the function returns.

This is similar for `r12`.

So if `SVC` calls a C function handler, registers `r0`-`r3` will be corrupted by the C function while other registers are maintained. In this case, the hardware does the stacking automatically, so that we have the guaranty (If the C function is correct) that all registers have the same value than before calling the SVC.

Note that for SVC, it would have been acceptable to know that these registers are corrupted (Because we know when we call the SVC instruction). But other exceptions (Like interrupts) have the same behaviour, and for these ones this is essential as we do not know when they happen.

Concerning a book, I know this book so I can advise it:

The Definitive Guide to the ARM Cortex-M3, Second Edition 2nd Edition
by Joseph Yiu

Comment: The real point is that the exception entry _itself_ looks exactly like an EABI function call (with the hardware taking care of the caller-saved registers), and thus exception handlers are simply regular C functions (note also how there is no special exception return instruction).

Comment: sir can you pls explain the TBB instruction also .......because i am facing difficulty with that i am not getting how it is going to the particular case and why we are writing the DCB() in between ..